# How to save image to gallery in flutter?

Tags: java, android, image, flutter, dart

I am developing an app to crop the images and I am using image_cropper and image_picker plugins.

I am getting the image from the image picker and then save it using the path provider to the app's documents directory.

and everything is saved and the file exists at the documents directory.

The problem happens when I try to save the image to the gallery using the image_gallery_saver plugin and it gave me the following exception:

```dart
I/flutter ( 2726): /data/user/0/com.example.cropy/app_flutter/image1.png
I/flutter ( 2726): File: '/data/user/0/com.example.cropy/app_flutter/image1.png'
W/System.err( 2726): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Cropy/1579080598267.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err( 2726):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err( 2726):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
W/System.err( 2726):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
W/System.err( 2726):    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo(Utils.kt:205)
W/System.err( 2726):    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo$default(Utils.kt:181)
W/System.err( 2726):    at com.example.imagegallerysaver.ImageGallerySaverPlugin.saveFileToGallery(ImageGallerySaverPlugin.kt:79)
W/System.err( 2726):    at com.example.imagegallerysaver.ImageGallerySaverPlugin.onMethodCall(ImageGallerySaverPlugin.kt:37)
W/System.err( 2726):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
W/System.err( 2726):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
W/System.err( 2726):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
W/System.err( 2726):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2726):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
W/System.err( 2726):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
W/System.err( 2726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
W/System.err( 2726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2726):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
W/System.err( 2726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
W/System.err( 2726): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err( 2726):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2726):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 2726):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
W/System.err( 2726):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err( 2726):    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
W/System.err( 2726):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
W/System.err( 2726):    ... 16 more
```

The method which saves the image is:

```dart
Future saveImage(BuildContext context) async {
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(fileImage.path);
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        content: Text(
          'Image saved successfully!',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.cyan,
          ),
        ),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'OK',
          onPressed: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**UPDATED**

- fileImage.path = /data/user/0/com.example.cropy/app_flutter/image1.png

Comment: Did you check before if directory `/data/user/0/com.example.cropy/app_flutter` exists?

Comment: `File: '/data/user/0/com.example.cropy/app_flutter/image1.png'` does not match with `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Cropy/1579080598267.png`. Check your paths.

Comment: In ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(fileImage.path); what is the value of fileImage.path ?

Comment: it exists and the paths are the same when I print the fileImage.path

Comment: the path is for the image in documents directory not in gallery

Comment: You did not tell the value of  fileImage.path. There are two paths isnt it? Provide exact info please. And you did not comment on `does not match with` . Why?  It looks to be the problem.

Comment: updated , I can't access the storage written in exception

Comment: There are two paths in the logcat lines you posted. These paths do not match. I asked you already twice before to comment on those two paths, Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the gallery saver package and migrate my project to AndroidX.